# Mysql error that I don't expect

Tags: mysql

Error:

```
Unknown column 'miahrose_pos104.phppos_sales.item_id' in 'on clause'
```

I don't think this should happen because I am joining phppos_sales_items to phppos_items, but it seems the query thinks it is being joined to phppos_sales. What am I doing wrong?

Query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE phppos_sales_items_temp 
(SELECT date(sale_time) as sale_date, phppos_sales_items.sale_id, comment,payment_type, customer_id, employee_id, phppos_items.item_id, supplier_id, quantity_purchased, item_cost_price, item_unit_price, SUM(percent) as item_tax_percent, discount_percent, (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) as subtotal, ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(1+(SUM(percent)/100)),2) as total, ROUND((item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100)*(SUM(percent)/100),2) as tax, (item_unit_price*quantity_purchased-item_unit_price*quantity_purchased*discount_percent/100) - (item_cost_price*quantity_purchased) as profit FROM ((((
phppos_sales_items 
INNER JOIN phppos_sales USING (sale_id)) 
INNER JOIN phppos_items USING (item_id)) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_suppliers ON phppos_items.supplier_id=phppos_suppliers.person_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN phppos_sales_items_taxes USING (sale_id, item_id)) 
GROUP BY sale_id, item_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think this should happen
>   because I am joining
>   phppos_sales_items to phppos_items,
>   but it seems the query thinks it is
>   being joined to phppos_sales. What am
>   I doing wrong?

You're believing more in yourself than you do in the MySQL RDBMS system.

IF an error message contradicts a cherished assumption, believe the message and check your assumptions.

This is a relatively wordy query, so the chances of making an error are not zero.  Check your code more carefully and you'll find what MySQL is complaining about.

Isn't this the problem?

```
phppos_sales_items 
INNER JOIN phppos_sales USING (sale_id)) 
INNER JOIN phppos_items USING (item_id))
```

> I don't think this should happen because I am joining phppos_sales_items to phppos_items, but it seems the query thinks it is being joined to phppos_sales.

I'm confused by this statement, because it implies that phppos_sales isn't involved, yet this snippet clearly shows that it is.

Comment: What is wrong with this though, it works fine in mysql 5 and fails in mysql 4. phppos_sales_items has a sale_id and item_id

Comment: The databases in versions 4 and 5 aren't the same, then.  Or something changed in MySQL between versions 4 and 5 that make this query illegal in the newer version.

Comment: It seems something with the USING clause changed where it tries to JOIN to the previous table. Does anyone know if the USING clause changed?

Comment: I'll bet you'd answer your own question a lot faster if you'd go to the MySQL site yourself and start digging into the docs.  Just waiting for someone to spoon feed you here seems inefficient and passive to me.

Comment: I have been looking: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html, I got the query working by using the ON clause instead of USING and it works fine, but I would think I should be able to use the USING clause correctly

Comment: I posted here because there are often people who have had the same problem and can answer it.